# Why Django prefers Postgresql?

Tags: django, database, postgresql

I have read from it's official document here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/

> **PostgreSQL**
>
> PostgreSQL is the most capable of all the databases here in terms of
>   schema support; the only caveat is that adding columns with default
>   values will cause a full rewrite of the table, for a time proportional
>   to its size.
>
> For this reason, it’s recommended you always create new columns with
>   null=True, as this way they will be added immediately.

But it doesn't explain what "schema support". Why Postgresql is more capable than others(MySQL etc.) on Django?

Comment: There is a video from PyCon 2014

Comment: There is a video from PyCon 2014 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a-_GAHfpk1Y, that explains difference in migrations between databases

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This reference is from migrations documentation. It refers to the fact that PostgreSQL is the only database backend included in Django which supports transactional DDL. That is Postgres can rollback `CREATE TABLE` or `ALTER TABLE` statements while MySQL, Oracle, and SQLite cannot.